# Is there a relation between Pauli exclusion principle and degenerate energy levels?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, pauli-exclusion-principle

Pauli exclusion principle states that two electrons cannot be in the same quantum state. If two different states lead to the same energy level, then this energy level is said to be degenerate.

Due to the fact that these statements concern the states of an atom, is there any kind of relationship?

Comment: Degenerate states have the same energy but there sre other quantum numbers, like spin and orbital angular momentum, that will be different.

Comment: @FrodCube Is energy level a quantum number? (according to my notes, I don't see this explicitly…)

Comment: You can identify each energy level with an integer number $n$ so basically yes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Pauli exclusion principle states that each electron occupies a unique state. How that state relates to *energy* specifically, though, is a separate consideration that depends on the system that this electron is a part of.

Without giving a long answer about [Hamiltonians](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamiltonian_(quantum_mechanics)) and wavefunctions, suffice it to say that the energy of an electron depends on other forces nearby (e.g., electric fields) as well as its surrounding environment (e.g., other electrons). For example, in a hydrogen atom — which contains only one proton and one electron — the energy of an electron depends only on the principle quantum number *n*. But in larger atoms, the energy may depend (albeit to a lesser extent) on the other quantum numbers *l*, *m<sub>l</sub>*, and *m<sub>s</sub>*. In most materials, there are slight differences in energy that occur due to these four quantum numbers (which determine the "[Aufbau](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aufbau_principle)" ordering of electrons in many materials).

So yes, there is a relation between the quantum numbers that the Pauli exclusion principle refers to and the energy of electron, but the specific relation depends on the forces and structure that surround the electron itself.